# findall module in re in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to get the output like "abcdef@aaaa.com" but it shows only "com" as matched expression. How do I get the complete matched expression using findall?

```
>>> pat = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.]{4}[\w\.]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*[.](com|co.in|org|edu)')
>>> pat.findall('abcdef@aaaa.com')
['com']
>>> pat.findall('abcdef@aaaa.com bsdkbsbd@bkdjb.orgkjdd')
['com', 'org']

Required Output:-
['abcdef@aaaa.com']
['abcdef@aaaa.com', 'bsdkbsbd@bkdjb.org']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the brackets at the end capture only the last group, that is `com` and `org`.

Change your regex to:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.]{4}[\w\.]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.](?:com|co\.in|org|edu)
                                            ^^
```

This ensures that no groups are matched, so that the matching string is stored instead of the grouped part only.

Also, I'm not sure why you put all those commas. I removed them and the regex is still working.

Comment: isn't escaping of the dot in "co.in" also necessary?

Comment: @user2390801 it will match an email like `abcdef@aaa.coiin` if you don't escape it.

Comment: @user2390801 no problem. Have fun with your new tool! ;)